# C# Crystal Reports Removing Duplicates

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am generating a report base on projects and their data, the original result for this is:
[image]
But as you can see there are a lot of duplicates...

I resolved this by using the following formula in the section expert for supressing:

```
{Projecten1.Project ID} = next({Projecten1.Project ID})
```

Now the result is:
[image]

This is exactly what I want it to be however, the prices are no longer correct...

I would like the prices to add up if there are duplicates so that:

```
160629 = 2312,5
170109 = 125,0
```

The current formula I have for the prices is:

```
if {Gegevens1.OpLocatie} = 1 and(DATE(ToText({Gegevens1.Datum}, "dd/MM/yyyy")) >= DATE({?ParStart}) and DATE(ToText({Gegevens1.Datum},  "dd/MM/yyyy")) <= DATE({?ParStop})) Then
(ToNumber({@fUren}) * {?ParTariefLocatie}) + {@fBerekeningen} + {@fKM}
Else if {Gegevens1.OpLocatie} = 0  and (DATE(ToText({Gegevens1.Datum},  "dd/MM/yyyy")) >= DATE({?ParStart}) and DATE(ToText({Gegevens1.Datum}, "dd/MM/yyyy")) <= DATE({?ParStop})) Then
(ToNumber({@fUren}) * {?ParTariefKantoor}) + {@fBerekeningen} + {@fKM}
Else
0
```

In case you are wondering, the prices are linked to the data (hours worked) for each project, like this:
[image]

So that's why it's duping the projects

Is there any way to remove the duplicates AND add up the prices if there are duplicates?

Thanks

Comment: These are not duplicates, but what you're after is [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223722/crystal-reports-grouping-by-values)

Comment: give a clear sample value and a sample result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group expert and Running total by using the created Group.

```
1. right click blank white section of your report > Report > Group Expert.
2. create new in running total.
3.select field to summarize.
4.Sum
5.for each record.
6.on group change.
```

Comment: You can use also suppress if duplicate. right click the field you want > Format object > common > Suppress if duplicate